# How to control or override the Client Side Naming of a Server Side Control in ASP.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to control the client side name that is assigned to a Server Side Control in ASP.Net 3.5.

I currently the following in an ASP.Net Repeater that just presents a list of a bunch of Yes No Questions.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="YesNo" ID="YesNo" runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
         <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

On the Client Side the following is what is rendered.

```
<input id="Repeater1_ctl00_YesNo_0" type="radio" value="Yes" name="Repeater1$ctl00$YesNo">
<label for="Repeater1_ctl00_YesNo_0">Yes</label>
```

I would like to be able to have the Client Side Name of the control be something like

```
name = <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionNumber") %>YesNo
```

So when the form data is posted I can easily Identify the QuestionNumber and type of Question.

Is there a way to override the naming scheme that asp.net using so instead of seeing
Repeater1$ctl00$YesNo I will see 4YesNo when the form is posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) Property.